# laravel breadcrumbs not rendering html in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, breadcrumbs

Within a Layout

```
@section('breadcrumbs', Breadcrumbs::render('messages'))
@section('content')
@include('layouts.breadcrumbs')
```

breadcrumbs.blade.php

```
<div class="fluid-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @yield('breadcrumbs')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Standard BS3 view with DaveJamesMillar Breadcrumbs

```
@if ($breadcrumbs)
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        @foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb)
            @if ($breadcrumb->url && !$breadcrumb->last)
                <li><a href="{{ $breadcrumb->url }}">{{ $breadcrumb->title }}</a></li>
            @else
                <li class="active">{{ $breadcrumb->title }}</li>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </ol>
@endif
```

Appeared to be working fine until upgrading to L5.4, now rather than displaying the breadcrumbs it displays non-processed HTML

```
<ol class="breadcrumb"> <li><a href="http://www.linkremoved">Home</a></li> <li> class="active">Messages</li></ol>
```

After reading the latest docs for davejamesmillar laravel-breadcrumbs with support for L5.4 https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/laravel-breadcrumbs/latest/laravel-breadcrumbs.pdf with reference to 1.4.2 using Blade Sections nothing appears to have changed in the way this needs to be coded. Unsure why the HTML is not being processed to display as a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAR, hours later! Appears Laravel 5.4 runs a `htmlentities` when injecting a variable into a `@section`

I changed

`@section('breadcrumbs', Breadcrumbs::render('messages'))`

to

`@section('breadcrumbs') {!! Breadcrumbs::Render('messages') !!} @endsection`

And the html is now being processed and displayed as it should.

Comment: FYI This should be fixed in v4.0 when it's released (but only for Laravel 5.5, not for 5.4). https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs/pull/140/commits/4ae5633f